# No se pudo encontrar el metodo 'X' en la actividad 'Z'

Tags: java, android

Cuando ejecuto mi código me sale una alerta de que se detuvo el programa. El código trata de una app de alquiler de motos. Que tengo que calcular el precio del alquiler por día:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private RadioButton radio0,radio1,radio2,radio3,radio4;
    private CheckBox CheckBox1,CheckBox2;
    private TextView tv4;
    private EditText et2;
    private double precioinicial;
    private double preciofinal;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radio0=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        radio1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radio2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        radio3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        radio4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio4);

        CheckBox1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.CheckBox1);
        CheckBox2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.CheckBox2);
        et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);   //CANTIDAD DIAS DE ALQUILAR 
        tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void importe (View v){
        String CantidadDias= et2.getText().toString();
        int cd=Integer.parseInt(CantidadDias);  // CANTIDAD DE DIAS EN VARIABLE TIPO INT
        precioinicial=0;
        preciofinal=0;
        if (radio0.isChecked()) {  //custom
                precioinicial=20;
            }
        else if (radio1.isChecked()) {   //scooter
                precioinicial=10;
        }
        else if (radio2.isChecked()) {    //crooss
                precioinicial=15;
        }

        /*if (CheckBox1.isChecked()==true) {   //con seguro 20% mas por dia.
            for (int i=0; i<cd; i++){
                double por = (20*precioinicial) / 100 ;
                precioinicial = precioinicial + por;
            }
        }
        if (CheckBox2.isChecked()==true) {      //con casco 1USD por dia
            for (int z=0; z<cd; z++){
                precioinicial = precioinicial + 1;
            }

        }*/

        if (radio3.isChecked()) {      //contado
            double porcentaje= (10*precioinicial) /100;
            precioinicial = precioinicial - porcentaje;
        }



        preciofinal=precioinicial;
        tv4.setText("Importe: " + preciofinal);

    }

}
```

No se donde puede estar el error.

[image: Acá esta la parte del diseño.]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el error que saca?

Comment: Si revisas el Logcat te dirá donde está el error. Por lo pronto, los bloques de `else if` deberían terminar con un `else`, pero en el caso del `radio3` lo que haces es empezar otro `if`. Revisa [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) al respecto.

Comment: Listo chicos, ahí subí el Logcat

Comment: Saca el texto completo, no necesitamos la fecha. (Scroll a derecha.)

Comment: Listo. @AsieR_2

Comment: No encuentra el método Importe(View), tú lo tienes en minúsculas. No concuerda con el que has puesto en el handler del button1.

Comment: Gracias totales @AsieR_2 !!!!!!!!

Comment: No relacionado: "Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te pongo la respuesta aquí para cerrar la pregunta:

No encuentra el método Importe(View), lo tienes en minúsculas. No concuerda con el que has puesto en el handler del button1. Es decir, debes cambiar el nombre del método o la llamada.

Comment: Con respecto a la pregunta existe un motivo de cierre: No relacionado: "Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos.